# Expressjs does not execute sequencially and function return does not work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to node/express js, and trying to execute the following. The control executes the lines after function call "var nextVersion =getNextContractVersion(cid)", even before the function returns a response. As a result the value for newVersion is not updated to Contract object. Also, function getNextContractVersion(cid) returns undefined, unlike the updated nextVersion.

How do i fix this behavior, please suggest. Also, is the right way of invoking function?

```
// Package imports
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Local imports
var { Customer } = require('../models/customer');
var { Contract } = require('../models/contract');

router.put('/:cid/contracts', (req, res) => {

    var cid = req.params.cid;

    var nextVersion =getNextContractVersion(cid);


    var contract;
    if (validateCustomerId(cid)) {
        req.body.contract.forEach((item) => {
            contract = new Contract({
                customerID: cid,
                startDate: item.startDate,
                endDate: item.endDate,
                conditions: item.conditions,
                price: item.price,
                author: item.author,
                version: nextVersion
            });

        });

        contract.save((err, docs) => {

            if (!err) {
                Customer.findOneAndUpdate({ customerID: cid }, { $push: { contract: contract } },
                    { safe: true, upsert: true, new: true }).populate({ path: 'contract' }).exec((err1, docs1) => {

                        if (!err1) {
                            res.send(docs1).status(200);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Error is adding a new contract:' + JSON.stringify(err1, undefined, 2));
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                console.log('Error is updating a new customer:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
            }

        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Bad Request - Invalid input!')
    }

});



function getNextContractVersion(cid) {

    var nextVersion=1;


    Contract.findOne({ customerID: cid }).sort({version: 'descending'}).exec((err, doc) => {

        if (!err && doc != null) {

            var currentVersion = parseInt(doc.version);

            nextVersion = currentVersion + 1;

        } 

    });

    return nextVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

```
Contract.findOne({ customerID: cid }).sort({version: 'descending'}).exec((err, doc) => {
        if (!err && doc != null) {
            var currentVersion = parseInt(doc.version);
            nextVersion = currentVersion + 1;
        } 
    });
```

The above code effectively says "Go to the database, find one of these objects and whenever in the future that is done, run this code that's in the exec block."

One of the ways to reason about asynchronous code from a synchronous mindset is that of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Here's a semi pseudo implementation:

```
router.put('/:cid/contracts', (req, res) => {

    var cid = req.params.cid;

    return getTheMostRecentContract(cid)
    .then(function(oldContract){
        var nextVersion = oldContract.version +1;

        if(!validateCustomerId(cid)){
            return res.status(400).send('Bad Request - Invalid input!');
        }

        var contract;
        var savePromises = [];
        req.body.contract.forEach((item) => {
            contract = new Contract({
                customerID: cid,
                startDate: item.startDate,
                endDate: item.endDate,
                conditions: item.conditions,
                price: item.price,
                author: item.author,
                version: nextVersion
            });

            savePromises.push(contract.save());
        });

        return Promise.all(savePromises);
    })
    .then(function(resultOfAllSavePromises){
        //rest of code here              
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('Error is updating a new customer:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        return res.status(400);
    })

});


function getTheMostRecentContract(cid) {
    return Contract.findOne({ customerID: cid }).sort({version: 'descending'});
}
```

As a matter of practice though, have the database control your auto-increment values. This code won't work in a high traffic environment.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I understand. However, I am trying to increment a sub document's field and auto-increment doesn't seem to work, hence the work around.

Comment: Mongoose should have the ability to run $inc on the document:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Found an example:
https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/how-to-increment-a-number-value-in-mongoose-785066ba09d8